# VueJS - How to highlight selected button when clicked

Tags: vue.js, button, highlight

I have 3 buttons that shows a chart when clicked on it respectively. Here below is the buttons for example:

[image]

Whenever the button is clicked respective chart is shown, but I want to keep the button highlighted with red color while the chart is shown.

```
<vs-button color="warning" @click="chartClick($event, 'chart1')" vs-value="chart1" v-model="show"> chart1</vs-button>

<vs-button color="warning" @click="chartClick($event, 'chart2')" vs-value="chart2" v-model="show"> chart2 </vs-button>

<vs-button color="warning" @click="chartClick($event, 'chart3')" vs-value="chart3" v-model="show"> chart3 </vs-button>

<script>
data () {
  return {
    show = false
  }
},
mounted (){
  chartClick (chart1)
},
methods: {
  chartClick (event, id){
    
    ...
    this.show = true
  }
}
</script>
```

Please help me in this, i want to know how to highlight the button, when the chart is shown.

And also i want to know how to display chart1 with button1 (chart1) highlighted when the page is loaded or runned at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding one more variable in data section, for example:

```
data () {
  return {
    show : false,
    activeChart : '',
  }
}
```

You should not use variableName = defaultValue, it should be variableName : defaultValue.

and then add to your buttons:

```
:class="{activeChartClass: activeChart === 'chart1'}"
```

Note: are you sure v-model is supported on vs-button tag?

also you will have to add this to your chartClick method:

```
this.activeChart = id;
```

and finally add a CSS class to edit your active button:

```
.activeChartClass {
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

You can read more about class and style binding here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Comment: Thank you so much, don't know why it is not working, your logic seems correct to me. Like where exactly i should place the this.activeChart = id ??, i have placed it inside the method chartClick at the end .

Comment: My bad, I have edited my answer now, I forgot to put : before class and that is necessary since we are calculating the expression there. So instead of class= it should be :class=

Comment: No problem, i had used :class only, but too not working. So my question is where should the this.activeChart = id placed , i meant inside method only but should it be placed in the begining or in the end

Comment: I have edited my answer again, take a look at it. Are you getting any errors now?

Comment: Also, here is a sandbox where you can try it out how it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-ride-9sn98?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank a lot, this makes some sense, i will try it out.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help out, if this ends up resolving your problem, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Hello @Mario Klisanic, hope your fine, can you please help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943006/vuejs-how-to-highlight-the-sidebar-button-even-when-displaying-the-router-view